# UITextView's text turns into NSBigMutableString when too large

Tags: objective-c, swift, string

I have an `UITextView` in an `UIToolBar` that appears above the user keyboard when typing. Everything works as expected, but when the `UITextView's` text becomes too large the text suddenly turns into an `NSBigMutableString` which breaks my posts to our backend. I can't find anything on why this is happening, especially when using Swift since the issue in Objective-c looks to be that you won't get a copy when assigning from `NSString`, but you do when using Swift `String`.

All I'm doing is:

```
let text = myToolBar.textView.text
self.sendComment(text) // text here is an object called NSBigMutableString when text is too large

// declaration of sendComment
func sendComment(text: String)
```

### Edit

I created a new project with simply a `UITextView` in an `UIViewController` and added a lot of text. At a certain point the UITextView doesn't handle all the text anymore and is returning its `UITextView.text` property as an `NSBigMutableString` object. Why is this, and how do I work with it?

Comment: "which breaks my posts to our backend" What do you mean by that? How do you send your data in your backend? Could it be that you may look for `multipart/form-data` requests?

Comment: @Larme no, because it's not a String anymore I can't extract any data from it. When I debug a string I can see its value as "some value text" but here I can't get anything, meaning I try to send a non acceptable value to my backend. This has actually nothing to do with the backend really.